# Set artifact name when using kfp dsl.importer

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When importing an artifact using the kfp `dsl.importer()` function, the imported artifact gets the default (display) name `artifact`. I would like to give it a custom name to make the pipeline and lineage tracking more clear. I checked the [documentation](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.dsl.html#kfp.dsl.importer), but I can't seem to find a way to change the name of the artifact that the `dsl.importer()` function produces.

Example code `dsl.importer()`:

```
    load_dataset_step = dsl.importer(
        artifact_uri=input_data_uri,
        artifact_class=dsl.Dataset,
        reimport=False
    ).set_display_name("Load Dataset")
```

Visualisation of the `dsl.importer()` step:

[image: pipelines visualisation]

I'm making use of Google Cloud Vertex AI Pipelines.

Comment: As mentioned in this [document](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-mlmd-pipelines#4), you can add the name of the artifact for example:`vertex_endpoint: Output[Artifact]` in the code. Let me know if this helps you or not?

Comment: When you use the `dsl.importer()` function, you don't define it like this in your code. This would of work if I was using a regular 'custom' component, but I'm not.

Comment: In the assumption that this is currently not possible, I opened a feature request on the Kubeflow Pipelines GitHub: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/7541